# jQuery .then() call two functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

If I have three functions `a, b, and c`:

```
function a() {
    var deferred = new $.Deferred();
    // stuff -- resolve deferred once async method is complete
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

`a().then(b)`

This works fine, but how could I also call function `c` after `a` is finished?

Something like:

`a().then(b,c)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mostly in all cases, you could use [done()](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/):

```
a().done(b, c);
```

Comment: All good answers, but I think this wins for simplicity :). Can accept in 7 mins.

Comment: Of the three answers, this is the only one actually answering the whole question.

Answer (score 3):

You can call the both function at the same time using `a`s callback function.

```
a().then(function () {
    b();
    c();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can chain them

```
a().then(b).then(c)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qghyq5v1/)

Comment: `how could I also call function c after a is finished` and not after `b` is finished